# subreport loop when horizontal print order with multiple Columns

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports, subreport

I had to deal with printing horizontal. I have created a report which a subreport. The Subreport is defined as 10 columns in a horizontal print order.
I'm having a problem printing the report correctly.

This is the design of the subreport:

[image: this is my .jrxml file]

This what its look like before I click print

[image]

When I click print the report come like this

[image: printed report]

But I want my report like this

```
Na    K    Cl    Ca
12.0  4.0  5.0   3.0
Na    K    Cl
5.0   2.0  1.0
```

Checked a few existing answers but couldn't figure it out.